# Content script/ background script ping-pong communication headache

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-chrome-extension

In my first extension, I'm trying to save my comments of a userforum in my own MySQL database which basically works.

Now I'm stuck in this problem: I need some additional information that should be collected in the background without 'disturbing' the user (same domain but HTTPS).
I'm trying to do that with an iframe in background page, one page should be load in that iframe, then some info is collected from there, then another page should be load in that iframe and some other info is collected from there.I came up with this:

Content script: submit button triggers background page to load URL in iframe

Background page: loads URL in iframe and sends message to content script that it is fully loaded

Content script: receives message, collects info from the iframe
 and sends it to background page. Then the same thing once again. Finally background page info via $post to my server.

In fact this ping-pong communication doesn't work for me. bg.js receives the info but I can't send it back to content script. Probably, I don't understand when which script is ready to receive info, when the content script gets info from the active tab and when it gets info from the iframe in background script.

What I noticed is that the content script gets info from the iframe when the extension is reloaded.

Manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "SaveMyCommenz",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "SMC",
  "version": "1",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icons/icon-19.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/icon-48.png",
    "96": "icons/icon-96.png"
  },

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.min.js", "smc.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end",
      "all_frames": true
    }
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["bg.js"]
  },

 "permissions": [
   "http://example.me/*",
   "https://example.me/*",
   "tabs"
 ]
}
```

smc.js (content script)

```
// ################# MESSAGE PASSING ##########################
document.addEventListener("submit",function(){
         // tell bg.js to load site1 in iframe
         chrome.runtime.sendMessage('1');
        //...
        }


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(response, sender, sendResponse) {
  if (response == '2'){// get Info1 
    //get info1
    var link = document.querySelector("a[href*='permalink']");
    // send info1 to bg.js...
    //tell bg.js to load 2nd site in iframe
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage('3');
    }

    if (response == '4'){// get Info2 
    var link = document.querySelector("a[href*='permalink']");
    // send info2 to bg.js...
    }

});
```

bg.js (background script)

```js
load_iFrame();

function load_iFrame() {
    var iframeX = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframeX.setAttribute("src", "https://example.com");
    iframeX.style.width = "90%";
    iframeX.style.height = "500px";
    document.body.appendChild(iframeX);
}
// ################# MESSAGE PASSING ##########################
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (response, sender, sendResponse) {
    //console.log("in bg.js angekommen: " + response.a);
    if (response == '1') {
        //chrome.runtime.reload(); // Kommentarseiten laden
        // load site 1
        window.frames['iframeX'].location = "https://example.com?page=1";
        // reload?
        // tell content script that site is fully loaded
        chrome.tabs.query({
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
        }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                "2"
            });
        });
    }
    if (response == '3') {
        // load site 2
        window.frames['iframeX'].location = "http://example.com?page=2";
        // reload?
        // tell content script that site is fully loaded
        chrome.tabs.query({
            active: true,
            currentWindow: true
        }, function (tabs) {
            chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {
                "4"
            });
        });
    }
});
var kom = document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='permalink']");
var i;
const kommentarSta = new Array;
for (i = 0; i < kom.length; i++) {
    kommentarSta[i] = kom[i].innerText;
    console.log("Kommentar" + i + ": " + kommentarSta[i]);
}
```

When and how I have to reload which page or which this communication should be done?

Comment: Declare a separate content script that will be injected in iframe urls. Declare the main content script to run only in normal page urls (http). Make your background page relay the messages.

Comment: thx for answer! how would i declare a content script to run just in iframe? i mean that are normal https-pages running there thx!

Comment: hmm, one url i'm loading in the iframe is https, the other http... :/

Comment: Okay, use a single content script and check `if (window != top)` to determine if it runs inside an iframe.

Comment: very cool, thx wOxxOm. but there's still one part left that doesnt work: (see answer)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (response.a == '1'){

load_iframe();  
//chrome.runtime.reload();      
window.frames['iframeX'].location = "https://derstandard.at/userprofil/postings?ortMode=1&groupMode=2&pageNumber=2";

        }


function load_iFrame() {
    var iframeX = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframeX.setAttribute("src", "https://derstandard.at/userprofil/postings?sortMode=1&groupMode=2&pageNumber=1");
    iframeX.style.width = "90%";
    iframeX.style.height = "500px";
    document.body.appendChild(iframeX);
```

}

the bg.js should wait for message=1 from content script and then load the the new page in the iframe but it doesnt. it saysthat iframeX doesnt exist. when i do the reload before there is no iframe in bg.js :/
thx for help